# Subsections for theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, punctuation

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

\begin{thm}\label{mmm} 
qwerty
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}
\label{ppp} 
qwerty
\end{defn}

Theorem \ref{mmm}

\end{document}
```

1. When implementing this code into LaTeX, my theorem and definition comes out as `Theorem 1.1.` and `Definition 1.2.` 
   How can I remove the `.` at the end? So it would come out as `Theorem 1.1` and `Definition 1.2`?
2. `Theorem \ref{mmm}` would  correctly as Theorem 1.1, but is there a way that would enable me to not have the need to type `Theorem` before the `\ref{mmm}`? I.E. I don't need to type `theorem` every time I want to reference to a theorem.

Comment: For the second question: Define your own command something like `\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}` in the preamble of your document. Use as `\thmref{mmm_tasty_theorem}`

Comment: thanks, is that a standard thing to do in a thesis or do people just type out theorem?

Comment: Well, they are simply equivalent so I can't see how it can make a difference in a thesis context. (I wrote two theses with it) Maybe I don't get your question properly.

Comment: The proiblem with "the \thmref command everyone uses" is that the first letter is always the same, i.e. one needs a threom command ref for the beginning of a sentence and one for in the sentence. Is there some way of making this dependent on a parameter so I can use a single command?

Comment: @David: [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) defines `\crefname` and `\Crefname` so you can use `\cref` and `\Cref` in order to capitalize the first letter of the object. In my answer I only defined `\crefname` since typically one would use `Theorem ??` regardless of whether it follows a period (end-of-sentence) or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In answer to your first question, this is the default behaviour for the `plain` theorem style in [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm). In order to remove this, define your own theorem style, say `mytheorem` using `\newtheoremstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% <name>
  {\topsep}% <space above>
  {\topsep}% <space below>
  {\itshape}% <body font>
  {}% <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}% <theorem head font>
  {}% <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}% <space after theorem head>
  {}% <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}% choose style
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

\begin{thm}\label{mmm} 
qwerty
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}
\label{ppp} 
qwerty
\end{defn}

Theorem \ref{mmm}

\end{document}
```

The punctuation is given as the seventh parameter to `\newtheoremstyle`. For the (default) `plain` style, this is `.`. Also, `plain` has `\topsep` as the "above" and "below" space.

---

In answer to your second question, the [`cleveref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provides an easy work-around. You define the reference name associated with that particular reference using `\crefname{<style>}{<singular>}{<plural>}`, where `<style>` is your defined theorem `thm`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% <name>
  {\topsep}% <space above>
  {\topsep}% <space below>
  {\itshape}% <body font>
  {}% <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}% <theorem head font>
  {}% <punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}% <space after theorem head>
  {}% <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}% choose style
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] \crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

\begin{thm}\label{mmm} 
qwerty
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}
\label{ppp} 
qwerty
\end{defn}

Theorem \ref{mmm}, or \cref{mmm}.

\end{document}
```

The above example combines a solution to both problems.

Comment: The `plain` style uses `\topsep` for "space above" and "space below".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks. It wasn't meant to be exactly duplicate, but I changed it anyways.